# Wrap text on any character, not just word boundary

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to wrap `TextBox`'s `Text` on any character as soon as hits the far end? By default setting `TextWrapping` to `Wrap` or `WrapWithOverflow` looks for word-boundary (space, hyphen etc.) to break to next line. I want it to break as soon as the next character cannot be fit in the current line, even if that means the word will be broken into two pieces.

Comment: Is this as they type?  You could insert a life feed in the text.  Part of the textbox works out where the caret is. The code for the textbox is here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBox.cs,77a66fa4f401a49f   You could build your own control with the exact behaviour you require based on that code.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks. That's probably more effort than it's worth. I've settled with an `ItemsControl` for now instead of `TextBox`, setting its `ItemsPanel` to `WrapPanel` and `ItemsSource` to the underlying string's character array. Works fine since my text values are not very large and I don't need editing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that I know of, but you may be able to hack it by altering your strings to contain Unicode Zero Width Space (U+200B) after every character.

Comment: mmm... that may have unintended consequences. My TextBox is showing base64-encoded strings that user can/will copy to other applications. Inserting non-base64 stuff will render it unusable.

Comment: You could always intercept cut/copy/drag operations and alter the clipboard, but that is just a hack on a hack!

Comment: Yep. That would probably work. +1 for being creative. :)